# Timed counter - decrementing of integer(JAVA)

Tags: java, timer, decrement

So my problem is that I would like to decrement the Counter integer after every "run". If i put Counter-- in the code(See comment) then I get an error saying "Local variable Counter defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final".

How could I now change my code to have the "Counter", int, decrement after every print of it?

```
 public void RunCounter(int TimeCount)  {  
    int Counter = TimeCount 
    Runnable Count = new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Counter); 
                //Counter--;
                }
        };
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture<?> countTimer = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(Count, 1, 1, SECONDS);  
    executor.schedule(new Runnable()  
        {  
            public void run() {
                countTimer.cancel(true);
            }  
        }, TimeCount, SECONDS);  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't declare `counter` as final, because if `counter` is final can not be changed later, do define int Counter as a global variable in the class..

Comment: Thanks, thought I tested that without sucess. Now it works fine.

//Isark